# Define column type in Kendo Grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How to define a type of columns:

```js
schema: {
  model: {
    fields: {
      "Field1": {
        type: "date"
      },
      "Field2": {
        type: "string"
      },
      "Field3": {
         type: "number"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But my problem is, I don't know how many columns I would have, and what would be their types? 
 And I get info about it here:

```js
$.each(MyColumns, function () {
  ("" + this.field + ": { type: " + this.type + " }");
});
```

So how can I get all that info, and stick it **schema.model.fields**??

Answer (score 1):

**Found a solution!**

```js
var lColumnType =
     $.each(self.columnsAdd, function () {
       return "" + this.field + ": { type: " + this.type + " }";
     });

schema: {
  model: {
    fields: lColumnType
  }
}
```